# a firewall is blocking remote assistance connections

Tags: networking

yersterday turn off internet and when i open troubleshoot i saw this text 
"a firewall is blocking remote assistance connections"

what will do i that this problem don't repetition ?

i using asus router , from router coming one cable and plugg PC .
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to open up a port on your router and your firewall if you want to be able to remotely dial into your router/PC. If you go to Control Panel then Windows Firewall then Advanced Settings on the left and go to the Inbound Rules pages and click New Rule to allow RDP connections through your Firewall. Then ensure you open up the same port on the router. If you can tell us the Asus router model we could probably tell you how to open up a port on it. It will usually be under port forwarding.

Comment: asus rt-n10e model. 

i net turn off woles , so other device turn off net only PC don't

Comment: what is idea? that i router turn off firewall probably i don;t will have this problem

Comment: tell me anything